# Code compiles but doesn't work! The cmd window just sits ideal and ideal but nothing happens

Tags: c++, c

The question is to evaluate the Sin(x) series using functions. The code compiles successfully but doesn't work, it doesn't even run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void sine(int, float *);
void factorial(int, int *);
int main()
{
    int x, fact;
    float sol;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    sine(x, &sol);
    printf("Solution of Sin(x) series is %f.", sol);
    return 0;
}
void sine(int x, float *sol)
{
    int i;
    int fact=1;
    factorial(x, &fact);
    for (i=3;i>0;i+=2)
        *sol=x+pow(-1, i)*pow(x, i)/fact;
}
void factorial(int x, int *fact)
{
    int j;
    for (j=1;j<=x;j++)
        *fact*=j;
}
```

Comment: This loop `for (i=3;i>0;i+=2)` will run forever. (Unless integer overflow turns `i` negative.)

Comment: 1) "_The code compiles successfully but doesn't work, it doesn't even run._" The code compiling does not guarantee, that it will work. Imagine you wrote an essay: all compiler did was to check if it is grammatically correct. It didn't check, that anything made sense. 2) Did you try stepping through your code, **line-by-line**, with a debugger, while observing the values of all the variables, at each execution step, to see at which, exact point, the execution didn't match your expectations?

Comment: I think you mean idle rather than ideal.

Comment: @AdrianMole even if integer overflow could lead to negative it may still have infinite loop.

Comment: @SlavasupportsMonica Anything can happen. Integer overflow is **undefined behaviour**!

Comment: @AdrianMole "_Integer overflow is undefined behaviour!_" I would like to add to that: **signed** integer overflow is undefined behavior. Unsigned integer overflow is defined.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` cycle in your `sine` function doesn't seem to be right. You're checking for `i > 0`, yet you initialize it to 3 and increment it in steps of 2. That cycle might only be broken when `i` overflows, but that is undefined behavior (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Integer-Overflow-Basics.html)).

Comment: @ChetanPaliwal Out of curiosity, what is the *correct* loop statement?

Answer (score 0):

Loop in `void sine` is infinite. You have wrong termination condition there.

```
for (i=3;i<=0;i+=2) {...}
```

Comment: How are you sure it's infinite? `i` will eventually overflow, thus leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Your new condition will never execute the loop.

Comment: @SaucyGoat "_Once `i` overflows, its value will be negative thus breaking the cycle._" Overflowing signed integers is undefined behavior. Hence - it is not guaranteed, that it will overflow into a negative number.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I corrected my comment, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Yeah... maybe you are right, maybe not. Nevertheless error was in this loop.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @Scalway You see Sine is an infinite series and I was caughtup in that infinite flow of the loop.